# Detect click in python

Tags: python, tkinter, onclick, pynput

I am looking to made a CPS(ClickPerSecond) application in python
I have made some research and finally have this code :

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button, Controller
import time

new = 0
old = 0

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
  global old
  global new
  if pressed:
    new = time.time()
    print("Click Detected")
    CPS = round((1/(old-new))*-1)
    old = new
    print(CPS)
      
with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
      listener.join()
```

This code detect right and left click and calculate my CPS.
But i want an interface with tkinter that just write a text variable of my CPS.
And the biggest problem is that i want to click every where on the screen and that will detect it.
But i dont know how to insert it to my code.   T-T

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution that I believe does what you want. `pynput` and `time` are not required with this method. Instead we take advantage of tkinter's `after` and `bind_all` methods.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

cps_lbl = tk.Label(root)
cps_lbl.grid()

#reset cps to zero every second
def reset_counter():
    global cps
    cps = 0
    root.after(1000, reset_counter)

#increment cps and publish results
def click_counter(event):
    global cps
    cps += 1
    cps_lbl['text'] = f'{cps} clicks per second'
    
root.bind_all('<1>', click_counter) #left click
root.bind_all('<3>', click_counter) #right click

reset_counter()

root.mainloop()
```

Alternately, instead of `bind_all` you can just `bind` to the `root` and force the focus to stay on the `root`.

**replace:**

```
root.bind_all('<1>', click_counter) #left click
root.bind_all('<3>', click_counter) #right click
```

**with:**

```
root.bind('<1>', click_counter)
root.bind('<3>', click_counter)
root.focus_force()
```

Comment: Thanks, your code work, but they just count click when i click on the window (it is why i use pynput)  but i will try to fix it alone
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat ironic answer to not fully complete question would be create fullscreen canvas on tk and count clicks on it.
e.g.

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()))

var = StringVar()
label = Label(root, textvariable=var, relief=RAISED)

var.set("Hey!? Are You Click'n or what?") # set it to Your CPS
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah it is possible but if i want to know my cps on a game, i have to detect click who are not on the window
Or try to make it entirely transparent except the text who show my cps and keep it active even when i am on a other window